# Is there a way to generate all Content Security Policy inline hashes at once? (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, .htaccess, sha256, content-security-policy

I am building a Content Security Policy for a Wordpress Website as per requirements for integrating a Local Bank Payment Gateway. Sadly, a lot of inline scripts are apart of Wordpress and it's plugins. I have to be manually whitelisting the hashes generated and shown in the console. I added:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'sha256-#RANDOM_CHARACTERS'
```

sha256-#RANDOM_CHARACTERS (taken from the console)

I have to be pulling these hashes manually, one by one. Are there any more efficient way of doing this?

I pounced upon the following over by GITHUB:
[AutoCSP](https://github.com/fcsonline/autocsp)

That should idealy generate something like this that I can just copy and paste in the CSP, but it doesn't work for me at all. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@halvor I have three hashes after script-src ánd 'strict-dynamic' in front of them and they work perfectly, no errors.

When you use 'strict-dynamic', suggestions are to use a nonce or a hash (and it rules out URLs, best is to hash all your scripts instead of using URLs, because you can never be sure that a trusted domain in your CSP will never be hacked, if it will then your hash prevents any other code-execution than the hashed one in your CSP).

Answer (score -2):

In this case the most effective thing to do would be to either:

1. Move all inline scripts to one or more script files, served from the same source this would already be allowed as script-src 'self' is included.
2. Add a nonce to all script tags. You could use the same nonce for all, but it must change on next load.

If any of your scripts are dynamic, a static hash will not work.